# Random String in merchantTransactionId posted to payment processer API

Tags: php, random, codeigniter-3, payment

I need to randomly generate a string to be sent to a payment processor to be stored as the Merchant Transaction ID. I am using CodeIgniter PHP framework. Peach Payments API docs say I must use "merchantTransactionId"

Ok so I have added `merchantTransactionId=` to the payment API request and tried to add GenerateRandomString to the API request and I've tried millions of other variables too, to no avail. The only time this works for me is if I use $amount, then the amount being paid shows up in the payment processors admin console, but I want a random identifier to show as Transaction ID as I cannot have the paid amounts.

Here is the API request code:

```
function paymentGateway($amount) {
$url = "https://oppwa.com/v1/checkouts";
$data = "entityId=8ac7a4c96afd0574016afd649e36013f" . "&amount=" . $amount . "&currency=ZAR" . "&paymentType=DB" . "&merchantTransactionId=amarechat_" .  $generateRandomString(24);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization:Bearer ******'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);// this should be set to 
true in production
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$responseData = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
return curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
return $responseData;
}


function request($amount) {
    $url = "https://oppwa.com/v1/checkouts";
    $data = "entityId=******" .
    "&amount=" . $amount .
    "&currency=ZAR" .
    "&merchantTransactionId=amarechat_" . $generateRandomString .
    "&paymentType=DB";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Authorization:Bearer ******'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);// this should be set to true in production
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $responseData = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    return curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $responseData;
}
```

so where you see &merchantTransactionId" in the above code, i require a random string of text/numbers to be generated and sent off to the payment processor.

This is the code of the front page that generates the payment form based on te amount the user has chosen to deposit: (this works perfectly fine. Only merchantTransactionId doesnt work...

```
<?php
$responseData = request($amount);
$a = json_decode($responseData, true);
//  print_r($responseData);

?>

<script src="https://oppwa.com/v1/paymentWidgets.js?checkoutId=<?=$a['id']?>"></script>
```

Comment: You don't define `$generateRandomString` within that function, so its going to be empty then clash with a previous. merchantTransactionId should **not** be random it should unique and associated with the user -> basket -> transaction in database etc so you can reference it on the callback/ipn

Comment: the database stores the unique ID under "payments_transaction", but even when i call that, it doesnt work